# Flatten Array of Any

Tags: ios, arrays, join, swift4, flatmap

How to flatten an array of Any in `Swift 4`. ***Example:***
Let's suppose I have an array: `var array:[Any] = [1, 2, [4, 3], [9, [8, 0]]]` and after flatten this array, my expected result is `[1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 8, 0]`. I try to use `flatMap` but it didn't work.

Comment: With a little googling.... https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Swift

Comment: @RayToal: Thanks, this link is so helpful. But could you share with me the `key word` googling to got this result. I just tried but did not got the same result. Just want to improve my search skills :). Thanks so much

Comment: Ah, I just recognized the operation as "flattening" (from 45 years of programming experience) and the fact that you were flattening arrays within arrays within arrays is "recursive" so I googled "swift flatten list recursively"

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ray Toal suggested (from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Swift) do

```
func flatten<T>(_ s: [Any]) -> [T] {
    var r = [T]()
    for e in s {
        switch e {
        case let a as [Any]:
            r += flatten(a)
        case let x as T:
            r.append(x)
        default:
            assert(false, "value of wrong type")
        }
    }
    return r
}
```

What this function does is the following, it goes over every element in the array and if it finds Int in your case it adds it to the result, if it finds an array of [Any] it calls itself (recursive call) and process repeats until every case gets to the inner most Int. Result is then returned at the end. Notice the `asset` that will be thrown if your array is not `Int`s and array of `Int`s (`[Int]`)

Then you can do:

```
var array:[Any] = [1, 2, [4, 3], [9, [8, 0]]]
array = flatten(array)
//result [1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 8, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reduce and joined functions of Array.

```
var array:[Any] = [1, 2, [4, 3], [9, [8, 0]]]

   var flatArray = array.reduce([],+]

else 

   var flatArray = Array(array.joined())
```

Comment: both of them didn't work for me. I got  the error with `reduce` : `Ambiguous reference to member '+'`

Comment: With `joined` I got the error `Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()'`. I use `Xcode9.1 beta2 Playground `